# API documentation: LSOpenURLsWithRole()

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Recently, starting Preview on a list of gif images produced the error :-

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Users/uki/repos/gif-fuzzing/test/234.gif.`

However on opening 234.gif the error could not be reproduced. This error keeps repeating at random intervals of time. I've been searching around for Apple Developer Documentation on what `LSOpenURLsWithRole` actually does, but I could not find any(which is weird).

1. Could anyone point me to where the API docs of this function would be?
2. Has anyone had a similar error before?

Comment: I had this issue, after an update to El Capitans xcode. A restart solved it for me :D

Comment: I hit the same `error -600` when I tried to run `open myapp.app` from `Terminal`.  My issue was self-inflicted. The app was already open. Why didn't it just send focus to the already open app? I had attached a debugger to the original app [ to a find crash ].

Answer (score 11):

fbernardo's link provides a good starting point... In this case, it's a more generic error as explained here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20191128225313/http://office.mvps.org/error/number.html#error-600

An inability to send a 'launch' event to the mach port sounds like a runtime kernel level issue... in my case, it was a zombie of a process I'd killed form the terminal holding on to certain resources, which only a reboot could solve.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and found a fix without rebooting. If you Kill the WindowServer the issue with Finder no longer opening windows will be resolved. You will be returned to the login screen, and when you login again Finder should be working perfectly!

Comment: Interestingly it is after killing WindowServer (due to general crippling UI slowdown) that *caused* `LSOpenURLsWithRole -600` error to start happening...

Comment: I had the same problem and also solved it without a reboot. Turns out Preview was hung trying to exit (from when I last [thought I] ended it). It wasn't a zombie (or at least I don't think it was) because when I found it with "ps -ef", I just "kill -9"d it and was able to relaunch it without the error.

Answer (score 0):

This function was available in version 10.4 to 10.10 of MacOS.
It's official complete documentation is here:
[LSOpenURLsWithRole Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1448184-lsopenurlswithrole/)

To answer:

> Has anyone had a similar error before?

Yes with many different applications and with many different versions of MacOS. For example, I am running a clean version of MacOS 10.13.5 where this function is deprecated. Nonetheless I have a process track which shows `/usr/bin/open` is calling this function.

See this other question:
[Old bug: The application “Preview.app” is not open anymore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424233/old-bug-the-application-preview-app-is-not-open-anymore)